# Fill blank cell value with non blank cell based another cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with filling blank cells of a column.

I have 4 Column headings in A, B, C, D.

I am trying to create macro to fill blank cells for dynamic data as per attached Data able wherein cell value in Column D is randomly filled and blanked.. Blank cell value needs to filled based on value mentioned in Column A..

I have created the macro but it's working to fill the blank with above value only and not getting the exact result..

Can someone please help...

[image: Data]

Below result is expected from coding...

[image: Result]

Below is the macro which I have created

```
Sub FillblankCells()

lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

With Range("D2:D" & lr)
.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
.Value = .Value
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to use a lookup formula based on column A. Currently you're just using the value from the cell above.

Comment: @SJR can you please help me with that.. I am learning the macro..

Comment: Scratch that, a lookup won't work as your data are not ordered, that would only work if the first entry for each value was filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary is probably overkill, but this should work.

```
Sub x()

Dim lr As Long, r As Range
Dim oDic As Object

lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
Set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'store column A for each entry in D
For Each r In Range("D2:D" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    oDic(r.Offset(, -3).Value) = r.Value
Next r

'retrieve each column A for blanks in D
For Each r In Range("D2:D" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    r.Value = oDic(r.Offset(, -3).Value)
Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work, it's based on the values in column C.

```
Sub FillblankCells()

    lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

    With Range("D2:D" & lr)
        .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C[-1]<RC[-1], R[-1]C,R[1]C)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @ norie... this is working fine if blank cells are exactly below or above of the filled cells but in case it is another row then it is not working.. I have made appropriate changes in question...

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list before using your formula. Something like this might work:

```
Sub FillblankCells()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngList As Range
    Dim DblColumnQuote As Double
    Dim DblColumnBuyerName As Double
    
    'Setting.
    Set RngList = Range("A1:D1")
    DblColumnQuote = 1
    DblColumnBuyerName = 4
    
    'Resetting RngList.
    Set RngList = Range(RngList, RngList.End(xlDown))
    
    'Sorting RngList.
    With RngList.Parent.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=RngList.Columns(DblColumnQuote), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlDescending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=RngList.Columns(DblColumnBuyerName), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
        .SetRange RngList
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        .SortFields.Clear
    End With
    
    'Filling the blank cells of the Buyer Name column in RngList.
    With RngList.Columns(DblColumnBuyerName)
        .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```